# How do I solve a Bind Exception in a machine with static IP?

Tags: java

I have made Internet IP static.I am trying to expose a web-service,while I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

And following is the normal webservice code.

```
public class HelloWorldPublisher{

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Endpoint.publish("http://my_static_ip:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
     }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Do your network preferences show that indeed the static IP is the current IP of the machine? Have you checked that port 9999 is not used by any other application?

Comment: netstat -anp | find "8888" is not showing anything,even it is in use,command with 9999 is also not showing anything.

Comment: And the machine IP (if it's Linux, you can see it with `ip addr`) - is it the same as your static IP?